# Yii2 : How to Customize Error Pages like 404 and 503

Tags: php, yii2

I have following config of errorHandler

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'page/error',
],
```

In the Controller page, in the Action error I want to check, that I got 404 error "page not found"?

How can I check it?

Comment: Yii::app()->errorHandler->error['code']

Comment: @Sfili_81 I don't see in the class ErrorHandler any array naming "error".

Comment: Sorry i've forget a piece of comment :). You can read this [doc](https://www.codevoila.com/post/24/how-to-use-yii2-error-handler) and then configure your errorHandler .

Comment: do you want to customize the way error page is displayed and want to get the error code that is thrown or only 404 error specifically? @Sfili_81 `Yii::app()->` is for the older `Yii1`,

Comment: @ Muhammad Omer Aslam you are right i wrote the code for yii1 :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are trying to customize an `Error page` and want to get the errors code separately inside the view then you have the `$exception`,`$name` and `$message` variables available inside the view, but in case if you use `yii\web\ErrorAction`, before I go ahead you need to see in which category you fall.

### CASE 1 Using `\yii\web\ErrorAction`

1. Inside your `PageController` you should have an `actions()` function like below.

   ```
   public function actions() {
       return [
           'error' => [
               'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction' ,
           ] 
       ];
   }
   ```
2. If you haven't created a separate layout for error add one now, it better to keep your error layout separate. Just copy the `layouts/main.php` and remove all extra CSS and js files or create `frontend/assets/ErrorAsset.php` and register on top of your layout file.
3. Add `beforeAction()` function inside your `PageController` like below.

   Sample Code

   ```
   public function beforeAction( $action ) {
       if ( parent::beforeAction ( $action ) ) {

            //change layout for error action after 
            //checking for the error action name 
            //so that the layout is set for errors only
           if ( $action->id == 'error' ) {
               $this->layout = 'error';
           }
           return true;
       } 
   }
   ```
4. Now as you have specified the `'page/error'` inside your `errorHandler` component's config so the action name would be `error` and so would be the view file, this view file should be inside the `page` folder this should be the path `page/error.php`. You have the `$exception` variable available which holds the exception object in your case `yii\web\NotFoundHttpException` Object. and you can call `$exception->statusCode` to check which status code has been thrown for the exception, in your case, it would show `404`.

   ---

### CASE 2 Using Custom Action for displaying Errors

Another Way is to use custom action inside the controller rather than using the `yii\web\ErrorAction` in that case you do not need to add the `actions()` function and inside your custom error function you should call

```
$exception  =   Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception;
```

and use the `$exception->statusCode`. Make sure you check for the exact action name for inside your `beforeAction()` function change your check accordingly for the line

```
if ( $action->id == 'error' ) {
```

---

### CASE 3 SHUTUP just Give me the Exception

If you don't want any of above and just want to check the Exception code inside the controller's `beforeAction()` you have to access the same `exception` object above but with a shorthand via config's `erorHandler` component.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

    $exception = Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception;

    if(parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        $hasError = $action->id == 'error' && $exception !== NULL;

        if($hasError) {
            echo $exception->statusCode;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the Case 3. Thanks.