# How can I get my Yii2 404 page to display on live server

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I customized the `404.php` page in the view folder of my Yii installation. Works very very on local server showing the website header and footer and the customized content on the `404.php` page.

However, when I uploaded to the live server, the 404.php page is not displayed when page is not found, instead a plain white page with the message - `Sorry! This page does not exist` - is displayed.
How can I fix this?

Obviously, the view/404.php is not being used. The content of my error.php is below:

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $name string */
/* @var $message string */
/* @var $exception Exception */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = $name;
?>
                <!----Section Title Starts---->
                <div class="article-title-wrapper uk-section uk-section-primary">
                    <div class="uk-container">

                        <div class="uk-width-5-6@l uk-margin-auto">

                            <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center">
                                <div class="section-intro uk-width-1-1 uk-width-2-3@l uk-text-center" uk-scrollspy="target: > div; cls:uk-animation-fade; repeat: true">
                                    <div class="page-title">
                                        <h1 class="uk-article-title">Page Not Found</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!----Section Title ends---->

                <!----Section Content Starts---->
                <div class="article-content uk-section uk-section-default uk-padding-remove-bottom">
                    <div class="uk-container">
                        <div class="left-indent">
                            <div class="uk-width-5-6@l uk-margin-auto">
                                <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center">
                                    <div class="section-content uk-width-1-1">
                                        <article class="uk-article uk-margin-large-bottom uk-text-center">
                                            <p class="uk-text-large">Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.</p>
                                        </article>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <hr class="double">                     
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!----Section Content ends---->
```

I have checked the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321461) but it does exactly address my issue. I did not change the default configuration for displaying error. The default configuration according to Yii2 will use - YOUR_APP/views/site/error.php to display errors. This works on my local server but is not working on live server which is my question.

**UPDATE**:
I have two internet connection. I switched my internet connection and I suddenly discovered that the 404 page was coming up normally. I switched back to the other connection and the problem returned. I have switched back and forth and it is clear that for unknown reason, I can get the correct 404 page on one internet connection while it does not work in the other. This doesn't seem normal.

I then used a VPN on the internet connection that is not bringing the right 404 page and it worked well too. Is there a security feature rejecting certain types of connection?

Comment: It has already been answered here  [Yii2: Customizing Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321461/yii2-customizing-error-page)

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam. This is different. I am still using the default error handler. I have updated my question above.

Comment: hmm ok , i overlooked it

Comment: is it related to the same app i answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379105/how-to-fix-yii2-contact-widget-problem-on-view-pages/55383088?noredirect=1#comment97494724_55383088)

Comment: It is the same website but different problem. I am posting an update above which I just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following in **web/index.php** or for advanced app browse to **frontend/web/index.php**

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
```

OR

You can throw custom error with status code. For Example,

```
throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException(status code);
```