# How to fix Yii2 Contact Widget Problem on View Pages

Tags: php, yii2

I followed the example here [Yii2, feedback form in a modal window](https://devreadwrite.com/posts/yii2-feedback-form-in-a-modal-window) and I was able to create a contact widget that I added it above the footer of multiple pages on my website using the code `<?= FBFWidget::widget([]) ?>`.

I stripped the code of the modal box so I am not using that. The problem I am facing now is that whenever I opened a webpage, the page jumps straight to the contact form at the footer instead of showing the top of the page as a any normal browser should do.

I followed all the code as explained in the tutorial so I do not want to post all the codes here. Please see the tutorial

How can I stop this problem.

Comment: if you stripped the modal code make sure you remove the JS too from the view `"$('#myModalSendOk').modal('show');"` is there anything on the console? caa you share the url for the live site where this is happening , it might make things more clear

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam. I removed that code too. I actually disabled bootstrap on the website so I do not think it has any effect. Is there a way to share the live site privately with you?

Comment: you can email the link here buttflattery@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `autofocus` property on the contact form field `name` which is forcing the page to go down as the cursor is focused inside the input field, you should remove that property or bind it only if the page url is `/contact-us` or whatever you are using for the contact form.

[image]

Comment: That fixed the problem. Never would have figured that out myself. Thanks!