# how do i change the layout on error screen in Yii framework?

Tags: yii, yii2

How to change `layout` on error 404 page in yii framework?

```
// web.php
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

Comment: This already has been answered here [Yii2 : How to Customize Error Pages like 404 and 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321461/yii2-how-to-customize-error-pages-like-404-and-503)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change layout for error page you have to set it for your error action. Based on config your error action is `error` action in `SiteController`.

If you are using default error action you should find something like this in your `SiteController`

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        // ...
    ];
}
```

As you can see the `yii\web\ErrorAction` ([see documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-erroraction)) is used as your `site/error`. This action has property `layout` that says which layout should be used. You can change it by modifing the previous code to look like this

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            'layout' => 'error' //use error.php in views/layouts
        ],
        // ...
    ];
}
```

If you have your own implementation of error action you can just set the `layout` property directly from the action.